# Error SpringBootServletInitializer after convert jar to war

Tags: java, spring-boot

I i  try to convert project sping boot jar to war.  so i add packaging type to war but if only do this  buid war and run with no erreur.
but can't access my web services. and if I add `SpringBootServletInitializer` I have this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.mysociete.BatchMyappApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
```

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mysociete</groupId>
    <artifactId>batch-myapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>  <!-- Change this from jar to war -->
    <name>batch-myapp</name>
    <description>batch Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.6</org.projectlombok.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.2.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```java
@Slf4j
@EnableJpaAuditing
@SpringBootApplication(
 exclude = {
         BatchAutoConfiguration.class,
        JmxAutoConfiguration.class,
        }
            )
public class BatchMyappApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(com.mysociete.BatchMyappApplication.class, args);
        
    }
    
      protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
            return builder.sources(BatchMyappApplication.class);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using Spring Boot 2.7.2 and where and how did you add the `SpringBootServletInitializer`. Please add the **full stacktrace** and not a snippet like you have now. Finally to which tomcat version are you deploying the application?

Answer (score 0):

make the class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
}
```

Comment: it's alreadys done